# Probability density function for the number of zeroes X in a five digit code?

Tags: probability

> Five digit codes are selected at random from the set {0,1,2,...,9} with replacement. If the random variable X denotes the number of zeros in randomly chosen codes, then what are the space and the probability density function of X?

I know the space is $R_x = {0,1,2,3,4,5}$ and for the probability density function, they all have a denominator of $\frac{1}{10^5}$.

Also $f(5) = \frac{1}{10^5}$ because $00000$ can only occur once. Now what about f(0), f(1), f(2), f(3) and f(4)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each position in the code can be considered a Bernoulli trial with probability of success (the digit being zero) of $0.1$.

Then the number of zeros in the code is Binomially distributed and so:
$$
P(n)=\frac{5!}{n!(5-n)!}(0.1)^n(0.9)^{5-n}, \phantom{aaa}n=0,1, .., 5
$$